# Using a variable in an SQL query

Tags: python, sql-server

**NEW VIEWERS NOTE: THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN ANSWERED**

If I have a long SQL statement in python that references a string multiple times, how can I change the SQL statement so it references a variable equal to the string instead?

In the program, the user's input will not be predefined. So when they put their keyword into the textbox and click "search", their input will be stored as a string, as a variable called "userinput". I need to use the variable "userinput" in the SQL command. So far, I can only make the SQL command work if I actually type in the user input into it.

I am trialling this in a small separate program:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE testtable (
        label char,
        format char,
        catnum char,
        sidecat char,
        year char,
        artist char,
        relname char,
        trackname char,
        composer char,
        collection int
        )""")
conn.commit()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO testtable VALUES ("GBI", "LP", "104", "104 (B)", "1974", "The Mustangs", "On Tha Rocks", "Someday We'll Be Together", "Unknown", 1)''')
conn.commit()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO testtable VALUES ("GBI", "Single", "235", "235 (B)", "1978", "Willpower", "Love Makes It Alright", "The Mail", "Eddie Minnis", 1)''')
conn.commit()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO testtable VALUES ("PENN", "LP", "002", "002 (B)", "1972", "Frank Penn", "'72", "The Time For Loving Is Now", "Frank Penn", 1)''')
conn.commit()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO testtable VALUES ("PENN's", "Single", "111", "A-111", "Unknown", "Jay Mitchell", "Nitty Gritty Song", "Nitty Gritty Song", "Jay Mitchell", 0)''')
conn.commit()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO testtable VALUES ("PENN's", "Single", "111", "A-111", "Unknown", "Jay Mitchell", "Nitty Gritty Song", "Unhappy People", "Jay Mitchell", 0)''')
conn.commit()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO testtable VALUES ("PENN's", "Single", "7744-7745", "7744 (A)", "Unknown", "Wendell Stuart", "I Am Who I Am", "I Am Who I Am", "Frank Penn", 1)''')
conn.commit()

userinput = 'penn'
cursor.execute("""select distinct label,format,year,catnum,artist,relname from testtable where artist like '%penn' or artist like '%penn%' or artist like 'penn%' order by year, label, catnum, year, format, artist asc""")
print(cursor.fetchall())
conn.close()
```

The above works... because I actually wrote out what would be the user's input, ("penn"). I know it works because the output is:

```
[('PENN', 'LP', '1972', '002', 'Frank Penn', "'72")]
```

**How can I change the SQL statement at the bottom so that it only uses the variable "userinput", while having the same functionality?**

If I just replace the user input with the variable "userinput", like this:

```
cursor.execute("""select distinct label,format,year,catnum,artist,relname from testtable where artist like '%userinput' or artist like '%userinput%' or artist like 'userinput%' order by year, label, catnum, year, format, artist asc""")
```

Then the search result is `[]` since it assumes that I am looking for instances of the string "userinput" within the database, instead of treating it like a variable containing a string. Therefore finds nothing.

**Edit: Solutions presented by users "SatanDmytro" and "Shiprex" both work**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
cursor.execute("""
    select distinct label,format,year,catnum,artist,relname
    from testtable
    where artist like '%%{userinput}%%'
    order by year, label, catnum, year, format, artist asc
""".format(userinput=userinput))
```

Comment: This works. 100%. You only used one "LIKE" command. Are you telling me that the other two were redundant?

Comment: @Jones659, yes!

Comment: I understand why double percentage signs are used, something to do with escaping. However could you tell me the significance of curly brackets {} here. This is extra, obviously, but if you know, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Define your statement before you execute as:

```
statement="select distinct label,format,year,catnum,artist,relname from testtable where artist like %s or artist like %s or artist like %s order by year, label, catnum, year, format, artist asc" % (userinput,userinput,userinput)
```

Then execute:

```
cursor.execute(statement)
```

Comment: I have tried similar things to this before making the post. Running your code now, the error I am faced with is "OperationalError: near "%": syntax error".

Comment: I just modified my answer to solve that issue. Hope that answer helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again. However with your edit, now I am given the following error: "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string" (occurs on the line where statement is defined). Maybe it's something small? If you know what's up, feel free to tinker with it and notify me of your edits, but if not, then please don't worry too much. The user "SatanDmytro" has posted a (different) working solution.

Comment: My apologies, I had forgottent to have userinput 3 times in the argument list, since you are using it three times in your query. I just corrected my answer.

Comment: The error now is:
"sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: penn" Clearly something is going wrong somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Please note that any time you use the python string formatting methods (e.g. %s, "{}".format()) suggested in some of these other answers *directly in your SQL query* you are opening yourself up to sql injection. See [this](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Rather, you'll want to use the [parameter options](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html) available and write more like this:

```
#format the userinput for the wildcards first - still in your python environment
search = ("%{}%".format(userinput), )
#pass as parameter to the cursor
cursor.execute("""
select distinct label,format,year,catnum,artist,relname
from testtable
where artist like ?
order by year, label, catnum, year, format, artist asc
""", search)
```

This way, the input is somewhat sanitized at the database call.

Comment: This works very nicely, thanks. Whenever I looked up similar threads, there was always somebody with a solution that was proofed against sql injection. The end program is meant for select individuals, and will be used offline. I guess tomorrow I will do some research on SQL injections and decide if this is the solution for me, since it's not something I am too well versed in.

Comment: The hyperlink in your reply "this" does not lead to a specific page, rather a home page of what appears to be a computing blog, what am I looking for? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, if the access is limited to trusted users, the risk is minimal, but it is good practice for anyone using SQL in python. The link in question is also used as a reference in Python's documentation; XKCD is a technology webcomic that has been around forever and there's likely a witty take on any topic you can think of (in this case, SQL injection).